# Xcode 9 compile error after integrating weex sdk

Tags: xcode, xcode9, weex

I builded the WeexSDK.framework by myself with Xcode 9.
Then integrated the framework into my project.
Got weird compile error log when build my app, could someone help me?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "___llvm_profile_runtime", referenced from:
      ___llvm_profile_runtime_user in WeexSDK(WXDisplayQueue.o)
      ___llvm_profile_runtime_user in WeexSDK(WXResourceRequestHandlerDefaultImpl.o)
      ___llvm_profile_runtime_user in WeexSDK(WXSwitchComponent.o)
      ___llvm_profile_runtime_user in WeexSDK(WXRootView.o)
      ___llvm_profile_runtime_user in WeexSDK(WXRecyclerUpdateController.o)
      ___llvm_profile_runtime_user in WeexSDK(WXRecyclerComponent.o)
      ___llvm_profile_runtime_user in WeexSDK(WXThreadSafeMutableDictionary.o)
      ...
     (maybe you meant: ___llvm_profile_runtime_user)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add `-fprofile-instr-generate` to Other Linker Flags solved the compile errors.

Comment: Do you know what does this flag mean?

Comment: Works for me, too. But I would really be curious why I've to set it. It doesn't seem to be related but I'll be happy to be enlightened :-)